# Boolean value from NodeJS webservice is not boolean when using in test

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I called a NodeJS webservice :

```
request({
                url: "http://10.210.210.41:3001/trackable/lastPos",
                json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    async.forEachOf(body, function (vehiculeJSON, cleJSON, cbVehiculeJSON) {
                        var tabFlotte = vehiculeJSON.flotte;
                        if (tabFlotte.length > 0) {
                            var dbJSON = rows.find(function(row) {
                                return row.num_tag_ip == cleJSON;
                            });
                            if (dbJSON != undefined) {
                                var num_tag_ip = cleJSON, etat = vehiculeJSON.state, coordinates = vehiculeJSON.position, immatriculation = dbJSON.immatriculation, lib = dbJSON.lib, msisdn = dbJSON.msisdn;
                                if (vehiculeJSON.is_outofarea == true) { // here is the test
                                    ...
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        cbVehiculeJSON();
                    }, function () {
                        ...
                    });
                } else {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

It returns values like this :

```
{
    "TMA0224": {
        "zone": 161,
        "fixed_at": "2019-12-03T09:55:49.000Z",
        "flotte": [
            {
                "type": "fleet",
                "id": "GAN.TELMAPROPRE"
            },
            {
                "type": "fleet",
                "id": "TMA"
            },
            {
                "type": "fleet",
                "id": "TMA.DVI-MOTOS"
            },
            {
                "type": "fleet",
                "id": "TMA.TELMA"
            }
        ],
        "state": "MOV",
        "numero_tag_ip": "TMA0224",
        "immatriculation": "1271TBH",
        "ignition": false,
        "mileage": 3263,
        "heading": 313,
        "speed": 2,
        "is_outofarea": true,
        "position": {
            "latitude": -18.90895,
            "longitude": 47.536675
        }
    },
    ...
  }
```

But at runtime the test never enters the "if" test. But when I replace the test by `vehiculeJSON.is_outofarea == "true"` then the test succeeds ! So why is the json supposed boolean value transformed to String ?

Comment: May be server is returning "is_outofarea": "true" instead of "is_outofarea": true

Comment: So if you do `console.log(typeof vehiculeJSON.is_outofarea);` you get `string`? Are you positive the API is returning a bool? Firefox parses JSON, what do you get when you paste the url in the address bar?

Comment: So why do I get a boolean when I test the webservice with Postman ?

Comment: @ChrisG I get boolean when I make the log, and in Google Chrome it outputs true

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
if (!!vehiculeJSON.is_outofarea) {
    ...
}
```

It should work whether it is a `string` or a `bool`.